# Do PyObject_GetItem and PyObject_SetItem work on PyType_List and PyType_Dict types?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, python-c-api

Documentation for PyObject_GetItem and PyObject_SetItem [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetItem) states:

> PyObject* ***PyObject_GetItem***(PyObject *o, PyObject *key)
>       Return value: New reference.
>
> ```
> Return element of o corresponding to the object key or NULL on failure. 
> This is the equivalent of the Python expression o[key].
> ```
>
> int ***PyObject_SetItem***(PyObject *o, PyObject *key, PyObject *v)
>
> ```
> Map the object key to the value v. Returns -1 on failure. 
> This is the equivalent of the Python statement o[key] = v.
> ```

foo[key] syntax implies PyType_Dict

However, it doesn't state whether it also works on PyType_List, in which case key would be an index, i.e. a positive PyType_Long, or maybe a type converts into it, e.g. a PyType_Bytes containing "42".

Does this function work for both containers?

I would expect it to; such a design to be in keeping with Python's "*it does everything you would expect it to do*" philosophy.

Furthermore, the project I'm looking at has a comment forewarning:

```
    // PyObject_SetItem is too weird to be using from C++
    // so it is intentionally omitted.
```

Should I be worried about this?  What could it possibly mean?  And has it been fixed for Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions work for all containers that support indexed accesses, be they dict, list, tuple, string, bytes, and so on.

I'm not sure why PyCXX has that comment; it may be due to the fact that Python's dynamic typing does not always mesh well with languages with static typing.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, I'm attempting to rewrite PyCXX (which attempts to create a corresponding static type for each PyType_Foo) with a single dynamic Object type that will mirror a PyObject. It sounds like you have already walked a similar path...?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it supports both!

You can find from the source code:

> ```
> pi@piBookAir.local ~ /Users/pi/Downloads/Python-3.4.2:
> ~ grep -R "PyObject_GetItem" .
>
> : 
> ./Objects/abstract.c:PyObject_GetItem(PyObject *o, PyObject *key)
> :
> ```

And looking in abstract.c:

```
    PyObject *
    PyObject_GetItem(PyObject *o, PyObject *key)
    {
        PyMappingMethods *m;

        if (o == NULL || key == NULL)
            return null_error();

        m = o->ob_type->tp_as_mapping;
        if (m && m->mp_subscript)
            return m->mp_subscript(o, key);

        if (o->ob_type->tp_as_sequence) {
            if (PyIndex_Check(key)) {
                Py_ssize_t key_value;
                key_value = PyNumber_AsSsize_t(key, PyExc_IndexError);
                if (key_value == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())
                    return NULL;
                return PySequence_GetItem(o, key_value);
            }
            else if (o->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_item)
                return type_error("sequence index must "
                                  "be integer, not '%.200s'", key);
        }

        return type_error("'%.200s' object is not subscriptable", o);
    }
```